# Invalid option in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Just started following a tutorial, however when I try to start my very basic node app i get

```
 if (VALID_OPTIONS.indexOf(key) === -1) throw new Error(`\`${key}\` is an invalid option.`);
                                               ^

Error: `false` is an invalid option.
```

I only have minimal code so far and haven't found anything for this and don't understand what could go wrong with so little code, commenting out the 'usefindandmodify' that has false doesnt fix it

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extender: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extender: true }));
app.use(cors());

const CONNECTION_URL =
  "mongodb+srv://<passandstuff>@cluster0.gber6.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose
  .connect(CONNECTION_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on port: ${PORT}`))
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

mongoose.set(("useFindAndModify", false));
```

Comment: Can you add the code more code of app.js and controller where it is throwing error?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the full error stack. It's not clear where the error comes from.

Comment: The problem is probably with the double brackets, try `mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);` Your code `mongoose.set(("useFindAndModify", false));` is the same as this `mongoose.set(false);` which is wong.

Comment: @Molda Yup that is it! Thanks very much, not for the first or last time I feel like a fool haha

Answer (score 7):

If you are using mongoose 6 these options unnecessary

> Mongoose 6 always behaves as if useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, and useCreateIndex are true, and useFindAndModify is false. Please remove these options from your code.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options

Answer (score 1):

Remove  this line from the code it will work fine after that as it is no longer used currently

```js
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can remove
`{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }`
and `mongoose.set(("useFindAndModify", false));` as others have said.

And lastly ensure that you've set your **username** and **password** correctly and is matching with the mongodb admin. And then it should work!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongoose 6 and above, the only thing you need for your connection is below:

```
mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL)
.then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`)))
.catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

Ensure you have set your connection URL and PORT.